# Which .bashrc file to edit

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi

On my raspberry pi (running raspbian), I'd like to edit the `.bashrc` file so that various actions can be performed at every login.

However, I have found two `.bashrc` file on the system: one is located inside the `/etc/skel` directory, while the other is located in my home directory (`/home/myusername/.bashrc`).

What is the difference between the two files? Does the content of one of the files override the other?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/etc/skel` is the template directory that will be used to create a new home directory when a user is added.  `/home/user/.bashrc` is your personal copy, and is the one you should change for your user to have those effects.

Answer (score 1):

The file located inside the `/home/myusername/` is the one which will be used every time you start a bash session.

The file located in `/etc/skel/` will be used as a template to create `.bashrc` files for any new users that are created on the system.